# Executing SQl Queries in C# using CLR

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, clr

I am using SQl CLR for parsing some table column. I want to execute the queries also in C# user defined function. Can somebody give an example to execute select and insert queries in the function?

Thank you in advance.

```
 SqlConnection objSqlConn;
    string connString = string.Empty;
    connString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=DB;User ID=uname;pwd=pass;Password=pass";
    objSqlConn = new SqlConnection(connString);
    objSqlConn.Open();

    string query = "Select count(*) FROM [DB].[dbo].[TableName]";
    SqlCommand cmdTotalCount = new SqlCommand(query, objSqlConn);
    cmdTotalCount.CommandTimeout = 0;
    string TotalCountValue = cmdTotalCount.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    return TotalCountValue;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you switch to C# you execute queries like you'd normally do from your application (using ADO.NET's SqlConnection and SqlDataReader, using LINQ to SQL or using your custom build data layer).

Comment: Are you sure you could use Linq to Sql in SQLCLR? Does the database project even accept dbml file?

Answer (score 12):

In CLR, you can use existing connection to run queries.

**Simple, returning data to client:**

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [table]");
SqlContext.Pipe.ExecuteAndSend(cmd);
```

**Returning data via SqlDataReader:**

```
var con = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"); // using existing CLR context connection
var cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from table", con);
con.Open();
var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
SqlContext.Pipe.Send(rdr);
rdr.Close();
con.Close();
```

**Running other commands:**

```
var con = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"); // using existing CLR context connection
var cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into [table] values ('ahoj')", con);
con.Open();
var rsa = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Answer (score -2):

To connect with the database you have to mention the database username and password in the connection string of your web.config file.

Comment: @sharmi Do you want an example to use select and insert query???Actually what are you expecting?

Comment: no, you want to use the existing connection as dizzy128 explained.